# Do doomsday arguments influence doomsday hypotheses?

Tags: orbital-motion, simulations, units, probability

The [doomsday argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_argument#Variations) supposes that **in the absence of any other knowledge**, if we know the age of something now, we may assume that we are seeing it in the middle of its lifetime and then calculate our confidence in how much longer it will last.

After much algebraic machination, if $A$ is the current age, $F_l$ and $F_h$ are the future lifetimes lower and higher than $50\%$, then $P$ represents the probability that the end comes before or after the future lifetime respectively,

$$P = \frac{2}{A/F_l + 1}$$

and

$$P = \frac{2}{F_h/A + 1}$$

For example, Mercury has existed for about $4.6$ billion years. Suppose I did a simulation that found that Mercury crashes into the sun in the next million years. The probability of that, according to the doomsday argument, is about 4.3 parts in ten thousand. Should that immediately prompt me to check my work in the same fashion as a perceived mistake in units or sign would?

Should we use other similar, but perhaps less intuitive (but somewhat easy) probabilistic methods to check our work?

Comment: Your example has nothing to do with the doomsday argument. Here's another: The Sun is about halfway through it's life cycle. This too has nothing to do with the doomsday argument.

Comment: Comets have been in orbit around the sun for roughly as long as the planets. But yet, if we see a comet, we can reliably predicts its death within a million years. That's because route application of the formula ignores information we obviously have - that comets are a transitioning population from the Oort cloud to something else. Then why not say that we have similar information about humans? No one disputes that fossil fuel industry is temporary, but this says little about the future existence of intelligent life. Your "counts" are either superficial (like a Ford model number) or weak.